# Implementing >> in a Linux shell using C

Tags: c, linux, shell, io-redirection

I am trying to create a Linux shell in C which would perform basic Linux shell operation. I have got > and < part working. But I am stuck in >> operation where a file is supposed to open in append mode. Below is what I have done for >> operation so far. Could somebody help me pointing out where I am doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
extern char **environ;
char words[MAXWORDS][MAXWORDLEN+1]; /* words on the command line */
int nwds;           /* number of words in words array */
int ignore[MAXWORDS];       /* ignore[i] != 0 --> ignore words[i] */
char line[MAXLINELEN+1];    /* current input line */
char *eveargs[MAXWORDS+1];  /* pointers to execve arguments */
char *ofn;

for (i=1; i<nwds; i++) {        /* number of words in words array */
    if (ignore[i])      /* skip those words in input redir */
        continue;
    if (strcmp(words[i],">>"))  /* loop through words array. skip if not double greater-than symbol */
        continue;
    if (i == nwds-1 || ignore[i+1] != 0) {  /* verify filename */
        write(1,NOFILENAME,strlen(NOFILENAME));   /* error message */
        fail = 1;
        break;
    }
    if (ofn != NULL) {      /* ofn is an outputfilename */
        write(1,TOOMANYREDIRECTS,strlen(TOOMANYREDIRECTS));  /* error message */
        fail = 1;
        break;
    }
    ignore[i] = 1;
    ignore[i+1] = 1;
    ofn = words[i+1];
    i++;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/* Setup >> file descriptor per redirection. */
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
if (ofn != NULL) {
    int fd = open(ofn,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        write(2,CANNOTAPPEND,strlen(CANNOTAPPEND));  /* error message */
        exit(1);
    }
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);
}
execve(path,eveargs,environ);
write(2,CANNOTEXEC,strlen(CANNOTEXEC));   /* error message */
exit(1);

/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/* Setup output file descriptor per redirection. */
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
if (ofn != NULL) {
    int fd = open(ofn, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC,0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        write(2,CANNOTCREATE,strlen(CANNOTCREATE));
        exit(1);
    }
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);
}
execve(path,eveargs,environ);
write(2,CANNOTEXEC,strlen(CANNOTEXEC));
exit(1);
```

Comment: Did you look inside the implementation of *existing* shells? They are free software (and `sash` is small enough to be easily understood)

Comment: You need to provide some [MCVE]. We can't read your code (because many declarations are missing)

Comment: Usual hints: compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Improve your code to get no warnings. [Use the debugger `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [strace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your comments guys. I have added re-formatted the code properly and added some declarations. @BasileStarynkevitch is there any link you would recommend? I found one, but I think the link is broken.

Comment: It would help a lot if you'd tell **how exactly this is behaving now.**

Comment: Currently, it seems like this operation is not working at all. When I try to append something to an existing file, the old content is overwritten (just like > operator).

Comment: The difference between `>` and `>>` is the flags on the `open()` call; the first includes `O_TRUNC` and the second does not, while the second includes `O_APPEND` which the first does not.  So, why don't you use your working `>` implementation and fettle the flags to `open()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's literally what I did. It isn't working. I can't figure out why. > operator is working fine though.

Comment: Well, you did something crucially different.  Why don't you show your working code for `>` and the changes you made for `>>`?  You've not stated how it isn't working.  Is the file not created, or is it not in append mode, or what?  Where's the printing that tracks what's going wrong? (Note that the `close(1); dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);` is both inconsistent (use either `1` or `STDOUT_FILENO`, but don't use both)  and redundant — the close is unnecessary because `dup2()` will close the target descriptor if it is open unless the source is the same as the target.) Will you handle 'no-clobber' mode?

Comment: No 'noclobber' mode. I edited the question to add < operator and changed 'dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);' to 'dup(fd);'.

Comment: To get the source code of *existing* free software shells, look on the web: [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [fish](http://fishshell.com/), [sash](http://members.tip.net.au/~dbell/), [zsh](http://zsh.org/) and *many* projects on [github](http://github.com/)